# Anyway to make a div UNDER another div clickable, like a shadow?

Tags: css, shadow, pseudo-element

So... I created this weird solution to a weird problem: I needed shadows with straight sides, like a gradient with clean sides instead of a box-shadow.

I used an :after element to attach a gradient to the bottom of the elements that needed it (in the sample, this is commented out).  I then tried an inset shadow with negative size and this works the same way.  These work perfectly except for one minor detail: I can't use it like a shadow because the elements it covers sometimes aren't clickable.

Sample: http://codepen.io/syren/pen/jlcym

Some things I've ruled out already:

1) Using inset-shadows on the elements underneath: It needs to be applied to the original element or else it won't function like it's shadow when things move.  If I could figure out

2) Using a box-shadow with negative spread or size: This works, and I would use this except it doesn't look like how the designer wants it to.

3) Z-index: It's messy because it's a very dynamic page, so I can use it in some places but not in others because seeing as its a shadow, it should be over everything visually at least.

So, to recap, I want it to look exactly the way it does with the clean edges, and I need it to be **attached to the element** not the surrounding elements and I'd really like it to be a pure CSS solution, like with pseudo-elements.

Any ideas?

Comment: In my opinion the `position: absolute;` causes your troubles. Why not just inset the shadow inside the h3 as a inset-shadow?

Comment: because in the instance in the codepen sample, that would work, but it would not serve my purposes globally as it does not act as a shadow.  imagine there being much more content underneath, and the nav is fixed, so as soon as the h3 scrolls out of view, the shadow is gone.

Comment: As far as I can see, why do you not just use an image? Like: background: red url(img/myimg.png) repeat-x;. This way you'll have your "shadow" and the background-color, and it's still clickable because it's the background.

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cuJqG

html:

```
<nav>
  <h1>I'm an Example Header</h1>
</nav>
<section>
  <h3>You can't click me because the shadow above is covering me!</h3>
```

css:

```
nav{
  border-bottom:3px solid #000;
  position:relative;
}

h1{
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  text-transform:uppercase;
  margin: 20px 10px 10px;
}

h3{
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding:10px;
  margin:0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 98.75%;
  color: white;
  background: #ff0000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 20px 40px -20px #000; 
}
```